# Turn off anti-aliasing of bitmap images embedded in SVG images

Tags: svg, png, antialiasing

I have an PNG image embedded within an SVG images. How do I turn off anti-aliasing for the embedded image? (Or, turn it off for everything including the embedded image?)

I've tried setting shape-rendering="crispEdges" on the image object, but when I zoom in using Chrome or Inkscape I can still see the fuzzy edges.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shape-rendering is for shapes i.e. lines and circles. Images have their own property [image-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering). You need something like this...

```
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
```

Comment: You linked to an article about HTML instead of SVG. Also, is there a non-CSS equivalent of this attribute?

Comment: Robert linked to a CSS article. Both HTML and SVG can be styled with CSS.  However not all CSS properties work with both  If you want to use style attributes instead of CSS, just use `image-rendering="pixelated"`.  Include both if you need to support all browsers.

Comment: Sorry, the first reference I looked at didn't show "pixelated" as an option. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/image-rendering